# GCP project ownership - mistake lost ownership

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

Doing some Firebase tests with users I change to ownership to another user and revoke it soon after, and with that I got the two users with "Edit" permission only and nobody with "Owner" permissions.
I tried through GCP console and API scripting to change that (even try using cloud functions) but I got always the message that I don't have permission, which is the expected behaviour.
I have a Gsuite account a GCP domain and both users are part of it. Any way to get this solved?
Help is really appreciated,
Rui

Comment: There is nothing anyone here can do to get you access to your project again. I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be sent to Firebase support.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I thought the community could have some ways to solve it, but I already sent the request to Firebase support team.